# How to get the checked items from kendo treeview

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, treeview

HTML CODE:

```
                        <div>
                            <md-button ng-click="getCheckedItems()">TEST</md-button>
                        </div>
                        <div kendo-tree-view="tree"
                             k-data-source="treeData"
                             k-on-change="selectedItem = dataItem">

                            <span k-template>
                                <md-checkbox !important ng-click='click(dataItem)'>{{ dataItem.text}}</md-checkbox>
                            </span>
                        </div>
```

I want to get the checked items from the treeview and save it as string with ',' between 2 texts using the get function $scope.getCheckedItems = function(){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that i need to specify 'items' as child. Here is the working code:

```
for (var i = 0, j = data.length; i < j; i++) {
        for (var x = 0, y = data[i].items.length; x < y; x++)
        {
            if (data[i].items[x].checked) {
                //Item is checked
                //You can get the properties using data[i]
                console.log(data[i].items[x].text);
            }
        }
    }
```

Sample data:

```
dataSource: [
{ text: "foo", expanded: true, items: [
  { text: "bar" }
] },
{ text: "baz", expanded: true, items: [
  { text: "qux" }
] }]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but in case if you want to get all the selected checkboxes inside your controller you can do like following.

```
 $scope.getCheckedItems = function () {
        var data = $scope.tree.dataSource._data;
        for (var i = 0, j = data.length; i < j; i++) {
            if (data[i].checked) {
                //Item is checked
                //You can get the properties using data[i]
                console.log(data[i]);
            }
        }
      };
```

Comment: Hi @PSK 
It return an error: Cannot read property 'dataSource' of undefined

Comment: This gives me now this error:
TypeError: Cannot read property '_data' of undefined

Comment: Hi! I used this code but when I go to the children node it gives me undefined values.

    ' var data = $scope.treeData.data();
        console.log(data[27]);'

Comment: data[27] might not exists in the list. did you checked

Comment: Hello! solved it. I modified it. Thanks! Very helpful! Posted  the solution. Cheers!

Comment: There is no "checked"
[dscythe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7587225/dscythe) how did you solve it?